# Updated my shell to zsh, command prompt now ends in a %

Tags: zsh, macos-catalina

I updated my shell to zsh after updating to Catalina, but my command prompt now ends in a % sign and when I run commands I get the message 'file not found'.

I reverted by to bash shell and it works fine.

Comment: `zsh` uses `%` like `bash` uses `$`; it's just a convention, and can be easily changed. As for commands not being found, you either did not update `PATH` using `zsh` configuration files, or you attempted to and set `PATH` to a bad value.

Comment: @MrHarvey : What is the content of the variables `PS1`, `prompt`,  and `PROMPT`? They define how the command prompt looks like, and you can define them any way you want.

Comment: @user1934428 He's clearly using the default values, which you could check yourself. It's not really relevant to the question. It's well known that `zsh` and `bash` have different default prompts.

Comment: I think it is relevant, since  he asks where the prompt comes from; so the OP nees to know which variables are relevant for the prompt, so that he can configure the prompt to any way he liked. BTW, I was not aware that there is such a default for the prompt, because if I unset PS1, I don't get a `%`, but simply an empty prompt in Zsh.